# Mvc 4, Modal window foreach picture

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

So i have this code here for the pictures, it works perfectly with the first but it doesn't update the modal for the next.

```
 <a id="modal-456343" href="#modal-container-456343" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal"><img src="~/Images/@(item.Id).jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;" /></a>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-456343" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">

                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                        ×
                                    </button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Overskrift)
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div>
                                        <img id="i" src="~/Images/@(item.Id).jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

i would like for it to update or create a new Modal when clicking on a new picture. do you guys have some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have duplicate id so it would just work for the first one, your html is invalid right one because every element should have unique id, just give then unique id to make it work properly like:

```
<a id="@("modal-"+item.Id)" href="@("#modal-container-"+item.Id)" role="button" 
   class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="~/Images/@(item.Id).jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;" />
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="@("modal-container-"+item.Id)" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

or this way:

```
<a id="modal-@(item.Id)" href="#modal-container-@(item.Id)" role="button" 
   class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="~/Images/@(item.Id).jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;" />
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-@item.Id)" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```